# spring boot with JSP how to get the checkboxes values checked from DB

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

I have checkboxes value with Orange, Apple, Mango, Peach and I checked Apple, Mango Click on Submit and saving properly to PostGRE DB as {Apple, Mango}

When I tried to display it in UI its not displaying properly

```
<c:forEach items="${checkedFruits}" var="list1">
   <c:forEach var="list" items="${allFruitlist}">
      <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
         <c:if test="${list1.fruitname== list.fruitname}"> checked="checked"  </c:if>/>
         <label class="form-check-label" value="${list.fruitname}" name="fruitname">${list.fruitname}</label>
      </div>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you looking at https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-form-checkbox you can solve the problem.

Comment: <form style="height:220px;" action="saveeditFruit" method="post"> 
 <div class="form-group" name="fruitname"><label>Fruits to Select</label>
   <c:forEach items="${checkedFruitsfromDB}" var="list1"> 
    <c:forEach var="list" items="${AllFruits}">
     <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" <c:if test="${list1.fruitname == list.fruitname}"> checked="checked"  </c:if> />
      <label class="form-check-label" value="${list.fruitname}" name="fruitname">${list.fruitname}</label>
     </div> 
    </c:forEach> 
    </c:forEach> 
 </div>
</form>

Comment: I see everyone saving to the db and displaying back as text not checkbox checked or unchecked.